# How is a JFrame actually created?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window

I am curious about how Java actually goes about creating a JFrame in swing; how does a window magically pop up? So, I went ahead and looked at the source code for the JFrame and ended up at the source code for the Window class.

In the Window class, there’s so much going on I can’t tell what hints at the initialization of a displayed window. I am a beginner, and even if it’s really high level stuff, I still want to be to see the actual code for making a window.

Maybe I’m looking at the wrong stuff. If someone could point me in the right direction or provide links, that would be great.

EDIT:

If anyone is confused by what I’m trying to ask, say you were to create a window just like a JFrame but from scratch, how would it be done? How is it done in swing?

Comment: *say you were to create a window just like a JFrame but from scratch,* - why would you spend time trying to reinvent the wheel? *I am a beginner* - so you should spend time learning how to use Swing properly. Start with the [Swing tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). That is how you learn about Swing and how to use Swing. That is how you learn about how Swing paints all the components.

Comment: @camickr thanks for the comment. I know how to use swing for a good extent, but I am unknowledgeable of how things work behind the scenes. To me, figuring out how to reinvent the wheel is more valuable than knowing how to work with a wheel and is why I’m curious about the creation of a window

Comment: The code that would create a "window from scratch" would be "native" code, code that directly addresses OS system calls, and for that, you would require C, C++, or some other language that allows close ties with an operating system. Java was built specifically to be OS-agnostic, and so would not be the language of choice for this task.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Yes I think I got that from the answer so I guess now my focus is on the native code. Do you know where this code might exist? Say for the Windows OS, could you point me in the right direction? Or maybe it’s not as easy to access this native code as it seems?

Comment: I have not seen any native code shared by the folks who run Java. If it were my money and I were looking into this, I'd see how the C/C++ folk do this, and then experiment with my own code attempts at this.

Comment: 100% agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels recommendation (see how the C/C++ folk do this)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Ah ok, I will look more into the C/C++ side of things. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window (or more formally java.awt.Window) is a Java API to the platform native toolkit window. All modern OSes (that support display anyway) come with a toolkit.

JFrame and Swing were a secondary attempt at providing a user interface (UI) toolkit in Java that would look and work the same way over multiple OSes. The classes in java.awt like Frame and Dialog were the first attempt, but they had native *peer* classes (see java.awt.peer - compiled C/C++ code), and rendered and performed very differently across different OSes.

So what is going on under the hood is that JFrame is first creating the most basic window possible from the OS toolkit, and then dressing it up (adding menu bars, scroll bars, etc) to be a JFrame or a JDialog within the swing Java classes themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that clears some things up for me, so you think you could provide a link to how basic window is created from the Windows OS toolkit?

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 It is going to be different on every OS. Here's a link for accessing Windows toolkit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/